# I have polished aluminum that has become oxidized from water. How can I restore this to its normal state

Tags: repair

Have polished aluminum that has become oxidized from water.  How can I restore this to it’s normal state?

Comment: It should be noted that "polished aluminum" is not a "normal" state.

Answer (score 1):

Use [aluminum polish](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/mothers-mag-and-aluminum-polish-0392983p.html), a chamois cloth, and elbow grease.